# After I Change my .htaccess my Css An Js not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

my project folders is like this

```
  *myProject(d:wamp/www/mywebsites/myProject)
     @ ajax
     @ asset
        #all of php functions and database
     @ newsPicture
        #my post images
     @ profilePicture
        #user images
     @ public
       -js
       -css
       -img
       -.htaccess //file
       -index.php //file
       -User.php //file
       -Posts.php //file
     @ view
       -header.php  //include in index.php
       -footer.php  //include in index.php
```

so i set my htaccess to this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Change /Posts.php?id=4 => /Posts/4
RewriteRule ^Posts/([A-Za-z0-9]*)$ Posts.php?id=$1 [L]

#Change /User.php?id=4 => /User/4
RewriteRule ^User/([A-Za-z0-9]*)$ User.php?id=$1 [L]

#Change /Sign.php => /Sign
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

and my html header is like this (view/header.php)

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/Normalize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/Fixer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

so when i pass parametr in my url like User/2 all my css and js not working ! should i use absolute Links for my link tag in header.php ? like:

```
<link href="<?php echo dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>/css/Fixer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

please help me tnx !

Comment: Have you tried using absolute links before asking this question?

Comment: Yep it works ! actually i add <base href="/myProject/public/"> in the <head> and it work fine , but i want to know is there any other way to fix it in htaccess ? or is it bad that is use <base> tag in my header ? or is it better that i use absolute links ??? which one is safer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change paths by adding a slash in the begining.

When you access **www.yourdomain.com/path1/**

The server search files in **www.yourdomain.com/path1**/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/Normalize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/Fixer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: what about user images and post images that comes from DB ?

Comment: i save images in db when user upload profile picture , like this : "../ProfilePicture/HJhbuGj.jpg" , so what should is do about this ?!

Comment: And why you save names with "../" and folder name?? What happens if you want to change the directory name? You need to save only image names. Paths will be like "/path/to/your/profile/images/{$imageName}"